# Is there a minecraft command to become immune to damage?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Is there any minecraft command to become completely immune to damage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This command will make you invulnerable to most types of damage for 277 hours:

```
/effect give PlayerName minecraft:resistance 1000000 255
```

Additionally, you can become immune to hunger with this:

```
/effect give PlayerName minecraft:saturation 1000000 255
```

Not strictly related, but this command will allow you to defeat the ender dragon in one hit:

```
/effect give PlayerName minecraft:strength 1000000 255
```

Answer (score -1):

Try playing in Creative Mode

There is also the cheat:

```
/gamerule falldamage false
```

in Survival mode

Comment: Downvoter, did you try these 2 answers before downvoting?